# Powershell script not authenticating TFS connection

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm having an issue with powershell connecting to VTFS(cloud base). My script has been working for years. Not sure what happened, other than updates that I ran from Microsoft which I think is the issue. This script just ran in april without issue before the Microsoft updates.

```
I get the following error trying to connect, which generally makes a popup appear for my credentials to Online  Visual Studios.

 if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell) -eq $null )
    {
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
    }

 # Variables - CHECK EACH TIME
    [string] $tfsServerLocationPath = "https://name.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"
    [string] $ProjectLocationToSearch = "$/Project/blabla/"
    [string] $outputFile = "c:\temp\RetrievedFiles.txt"
    [string] $dateRange = "D2018-04-18 00:00:00Z~"
    [bool]   $openOutputFile = $true 
    $AutoDeployDir = "$/Project/blabla/"
    $deployDirectory = "C:\Temp\ReleaseTest\DeployFiles\" 
    $tfsCollection = New-Object -TypeName  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection -ArgumentList $tfsServerLocationPath
    $tfsVersionControl = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])


**AFTER THIS LINE IS WHEN THE ERROR APPEARS.**
    [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfs = get-tfsserver  $tfsServerLocationPath 


    get-tfsserver : Key not valid for use in specified state.
At line:31 char:67
+ [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfs = get-tfsserver  ...
+                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-TfsServer], CryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetTfsServer,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.GetTf 
   sServerCommand

Thank You in Advance.
```

Comment: Have you ever changed your account password before? And what client   are you using? VS 2015 or VS 2017 or others?

Comment: Andy - I'm using powerShell with the snapin for tfs. I run this script from PowerShell ISE as administrator which just ran in April without issue. I run this script once a month for retrieving release files for deployment. After April I ran the Microsoft updates. I looked at my update history and I didn't see anything that appeared to be the culprit. This happened to me before a few years ago, and I can't remember what package/msi I needed to run to get around this.

Comment: What's the OS version? What about specifying the credential explicitly something like:  `$tfs = get-tfsserver  $tfsServerLocationPath  -credential $credential -all`.  If that still not work, could you please share the complete script here for troubleshoot?

Comment: Andy I'm on Windows 7 latest updates have been applied. Please keep in mine this was all working. The script portion that I posted above is the portion from top to the failure as indicated. The rest of the script has nothing to do issue. That portion should execute and the popup for the login credentials should display. The TFS they we are using is the cloud base one, not on premise. The code you provided doesn't work. I appreciate the suggestion. I get the same error.

Comment: Here is the error get-tfsserver : Key not valid for use in specified state.
At line:17 char:67
+ [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfs = 
get-tfsserver  ...
+                                                                   
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-TfsServer], Cryptograp 
   hicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetTfsServer,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools 
   .PowerShell.GetTfsServerCommand

Comment: FYI - The usual popup was a browser one.

Comment: Cannot figure it out based on the current limited information, whatever just try to uninstall the TFS PowerTools, then re-install it again to check if that works.

Comment: WOW - my lucky day, for all of you that have the same issue as I did. Here is the fix. I had to delete this registry key.                                                                                              HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage.                                                I found here at the following Post. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2014/01/10/vs2013-tfs-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state-error/.                                  Andy, I appreciate your suggestions Sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW - my lucky day, for all of you that have the same issue as I did. Here is the fix. I had to delete this registry key. 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage.

I found here at the following Post.

http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2014/01/10/